# How to accept the props value while not keep on repeating the object

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm a newbie in this framework and this is my inline-template

```
<edit-profile inline-template :user="{{ $user }}">
```

```
export default {

  props: ['user'],

 form : { 
        display_name : "",
        username  : "",
        email : "",
        first_name : "",
        middle_name : "",
        last_name : "",
        telephone : "",
        mobile : "",
        skype : "",
        facebook: "",
        twitter : "",
        instagram  : "",
        bio : ""
      },
};
```

But i don't want to repeat the this.user.xxxx like this.form.username in every field in the form object. How can I not repeat it ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you think about it. `user` is just an object and, maybe, you can just assign it to `form` when the component is `mounted()`?

```
export default {

    props: ['user'],

    data: {
        form: {}
    },  

    mounted()
    {
        this.form = this.user; 
    }

};
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yeah lol :) I never thougth of that that's definitely the right one